# How to use tf.GPUOptions.Experimental in session config?

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems that I must be able to set up a session using [tf.GPUOptions.Experimental](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GPUOptions/Experimental) properties, such as `use_unified_memory`.

But next thing doesn't work:

```
cfg = tf.ConfigProto()
cfg.gpu_options.experimental.use_unified_memory = True
#AttributeError: Assignment not allowed (no field "use_unified_memory" in protocol message object).
td.Session(cfg)
```

Neither this:

```
cfg = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions.Experimental())
#TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected tensorflow.GPUOptions got tensorflow.GPUOptions.Experimental.
```

How can use *session(config)* with *tf.GPUOptions.Experimental* ?

Comment: I just run `cfg = tf.ConfigProto(); cfg.gpu_options.experimental.use_unified_memory = True; sess = tf.Session(config=cfg)` both in 1.14.0 (CPU) and 1.12.0 (GPU) and it seems to work for me.

Comment: Thank you @jdehesa. While I was convinced that I am using 1.13, it was not the case